# How can I solve 'ServerManager' object has no attribute 'user_info' error in postgresql pqAdmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm trying to create a server for an existing database using postgresql but i'm getting this error **'ServerManager' object has no attribute 'user_info'** can someone please assist me to overcome this error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated PG Admin to v6.16 and it worked for me. https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v6.16/macos/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error while connecting to an old instance of PostgreSQL from pgAdmin-4.
Remember that

> pgAdmin III may not function as expected. Supported server versions (of pgAdmin III) are 8.4 to 9.4.

so pgAdmin-4 range starts from PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: Downgraded to pgAdmin lll, then I managed to access the old database
Thank you.

Answer (score 56):

I was getting the same error. Just use pgadmin4 version 6.15 or newer. It solved my problem.

Comment: pgadmin4 version 6.11 worked for me

Comment: Remove and install new version fixed my issue.

Comment: 7.5 works for me!

Comment: Makes sense to upgrade for newer versions of postgreSQL. Solution worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I was getting this error because in Postgres version 15 and letter column "datlastsysoid" from the table "pg_database" has been removed. You can visit this [link](https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_database.html)

So in this case you can use Postgres version 14 or earlier versions.

Comment: For Postgres 15 you have to use pgadmin4 version 6.15 or newer.

Comment: @Nils this is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

I've used just an older **pg db** version, and it worked!

Comment: You are saying thanks for existing answers but do not contribute anything new, right? In that case please delete this post and use your voting privilege to express your gratitude. Otherwise please [edit] to make your new insight more obvious please.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error it seemed to be because I had installed pgAdmin (a newer version) separately from the full PostgreSQL install which included pgAdmin. I uninstalled the separate installation of pgAdmin this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I had postgreSQL 14 and 15 installed. I removed the newer version I installed separately from the full PostgreSQL install which included pgAdmin, uninstalled postgreSQL 14 and removed the file (c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data) and it worked.

Answer (score -4):

Just try to remove the pgAdmin folder from the C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin and restarted the pgAdmin and it should work.